# VueX Getter acting reactively - how to assign non-reactive to variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am running into a bit of a quirk that I can't seem to wrap my head around and don't know if this is the standard behavior of VueX or if I'm implementing this incorrectly.

I have a VueX getter on a modular store that I am assigning to a new variable. When I attempt to manipulate the newly assigned variable, it also updates state - how can I just create a non-reactive duplicate of the getter result?

Here is my VueX code:

```
export const getters = {
  getActiveFilters: (state) => {
    return state.filters.filter(filter => {
       return filter.status === 'active';
    });
  },
};
```

I then have a method that uses the function in a dynamic class comparator - essentially it returns true or false as to whether or not a list of items is empty with the addition of a new filter.

```
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="filter in $store.getters['filters/getActiveFilters']"
    :key="filter.id"
    :class="{disabled: !isSelectable(filter.name, filter.value)}"
  >{{ filter.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the method that is doing a bit of calculation / manipulation before returning a bool:

```
isSelectable(name, value) {
  const activeFilters = this.$store.getters['filters/getActiveFilters'];

  /* Here's the part that is screwing up and manipulating the getter result */
  activeFilters.push({name, value, id: 'test-id'});

  let valid = false
  this.activeFilters.forEach(filter => {
   // valid = true;
  });
  return valid;
},
```

console.log(this.$store.getters['filters/getActiveFilters']) will return the results with the new value added, even though it was added to a different variable - so in the instance of using this in v-for - the list continually gets bigger every time.

Any idea on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The getter `$store.getters['filters/getActiveFilters']` will return same(cached) result(reference to array) if there is no changes in `state.filters`. So when you push some element you push it to the cached filtered array that is referenced in other parts of app. 
Just copy array with `slice` to avoid changing cached value:

```
const activeFilters = this.$store.getters['filters/getActiveFilters'].slice();
```

P.S. This is just shallow copy, so if you want to change some item property - use mutations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to the problem:

```
const activeFilters = [...this.$store.getters['filters/getActiveFilters']]
```

This method create copy of array and this copy is not associated with vuex objects.
For save changed values, you must use mutations.
God luck.